# Problem With Return Two Parameter From Controller In Laravel to Ajax

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, return-value

i have a problem in may controller for send 2 result to may ajax:

```
$validData = $request->validate([
        'id' => "required"
    ]);

    $category_name = Category::where('parent', $validData['id'])->pluck('name');
    $category_id = Category::where('parent', $validData['id'])->pluck('id');
    return response($category_name , $category_id);
```

how can send $category_name , $category_id ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
return response([
'category_id' => $category_id,
'category_name' => $category_name
]);
```

Than you can catch the response as `response.category_id`

Answer (score 1):

```
return response()->json(["category_name" => $category_name , "category_id" => 
$category_id]);
```

Try this code.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$out = array('category_id' => $category_id, 'category_name' => $category_name);
return response()->json($out);
```

Using this will set proper response content type as json and in your ajax success response you can take vales as **response.category_id** or **response.category_name**.